# Error when I try to extract info in a json

Tags: python, api

I have this code:

```
api_key = "_________"

ciudad = input("put the city: ")

url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" +ciudad+ "&appid=" + api_key
print(url)     

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

js = json.loads(data)
```

And it is all okey

but I need the temp max and min and I try this:

```
for res in js["list"][0]["main"]:
    print("the value of", res["main.temp_min"])
```

and the code give me this error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The json it is like:

```
{'cod': '200', 'message': 0, 'cnt': 40, 'list': [{'dt': 1669032000, 'main': {'temp': 288.99, 'feels_like': 288.35, 'temp_min': 286.43, 'temp_max': 288.99, 'pressure': 1012, 'sea_level': 1012, 'grnd_level': 1007, 'humidity': 66, 'temp_kf': 2.56}, 'weather': [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'light rain', 'icon': '10d'}], 'clouds': {'all': 75}, 'wind': {'speed': 9.85, 'deg': 296, 'gust': 13.2}, 'visibility': 10000, 'pop': 1, 'rain': {'3h': 1.55}, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2022-11-21 12:00:00'}, {'dt': 1669042800, 'main': {'temp': 287.59, 'feels_like': 286.94, 'temp_min': 284.8, 'temp_max': 287.59, 'pressure': 1014, 'sea_level': 1014, 'grnd_level': 1008, 'humidity': 71, 'temp_kf': 2.79}, 'weather': [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'light rain', 'icon': '10d'}], 'clouds': {'all': 78}, 'wind': {'speed': 9.77, 'deg': 314, 'gust': 14.1}, 'visibility': 10000, 'pop': 1, 'rain': {'3h': 2.28}, 'sys': {'pod': 'd'}, 'dt_txt': '2022-11-21 15:00:00'}, {'dt': 1669053600, 'main': {'temp': 286.12, 'feels_like': 285.14, 'temp_min': 284.68, 'temp_max': 286.12, 'pressure': 1016, 'sea_level': 1016, 'grnd_level': 1009, 'humidity': 64, 'temp_kf': 1.44}, 'weather': [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'light rain', 'icon': '10n'}], 'clouds': {'all': 86}, 'wind': {'speed': 8.5, 'deg': 308, 'gust': 12.41}, 'visibility': 10000, 'pop': 1, 'rain': {'3h': 1.46}, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2022-11-21 18:00:00'}, {'dt': 1669064400, 'main': {'temp': 284.63, 'feels_like': 283.53, 'temp_min': 284.63, 'temp_max': 284.63, 'pressure': 1019, 'sea_level': 1019, 'grnd_level': 1010, 'humidity': 65, 'temp_kf': 0}, 'weather': [{'id': 500, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'light rain', 'icon': '10n'}], 'clouds': {'all': 100}, 'wind': {'speed': 7.04, 'deg': 300, 'gust': 10.08}, 'visibility': 10000, 'pop': 0.57, 'rain': {'3h': 0.42}, 'sys': {'pod': 'n'}, 'dt_txt': '2022-11-21 21:00:00'}, {'dt': 1669075200, 'main': {'temp': 284.82, 'feels_like': 283.95, 'temp_min': 284.82, 'temp_max': 284.82, 'pressure': 1018, 'sea_level': 1018, 'grnd_level': 1009, 'humidity': 73, 'temp_kf': 0}
```

Comment: "*The json it is like*"--That isn't JSON.

Comment: You've got a 4 deep nested access in a single expression. Get rid of the `for` loop, split it up, one per line of code, printing after each one, and see what value isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @JaredSmith I dont understand so well, how I split the loop in four lines?

Comment: You are reading the "main" key of the first item of the "list" key of the js dictionary. Split *that* up in to for lines: `print(js["list"]); print(js["list"][0]);` etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js["list"][0]["main"]` is a dictionary:

```
{'temp': 288.99, 'feels_like': 288.35, 'temp_min': 286.43, 'temp_max': 288.99, 'pressure': 1012, 'sea_level': 1012, 'grnd_level': 1007, 'humidity': 66, 'temp_kf': 2.56}
```

`for res in js["list"][0]["main"]` iterates over its keys. So `res` is one of the keys in this dictionary which are strings (hence the error). What you probably want is:

```
for l in js["list"]:
    print("the value of", l["main"]["temp_min"])
```